# Is the tensor algebra on a differential ring a differential ring, naturally?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a unitary ring and $V$ an $A$-module which is also a differential ring.

Is the tensor algebra $\bigoplus_{n\ge 0} V^{\otimes n}$ a differential ring in a natural way? Is there a formal proof of this (I dream one that uses the universal property of the tensor algebra!)?

It seems to me that $d^\otimes$ can be characterized by some properties: it is a derivation defined on degree $N$-monomials, it behaves like a standard derivation on polynomial rings when restrictd to the subspace of symmetric tensors, etc etc. Is this guess correct?

This question is actually a tentative abstraction of the wikipedia page on [tensor derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [arXiv preprint 1106.1856](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1856)

J. Terilla, T. Tradler, S. O. Wilson: *Homotopy DG algebras induce homotopy BV algebras* (2011)

is close to what you are looking for. In fact, the abstracts says

> Let $TA$ denote the space underlying the tensor algebra of a vector space $A$. In this short note, we show that if $A$ is a differential graded algebra, then $TA$ is a differential Batalin-Vilkovisky algebra. Moreover, if $A$ is an $A$-infinity algebra, then $TA$ is a commutative BV-infinity algebra.

Comment: I have let this answer dry for a while and still can't feel satisfied. Why do you have to invoke such a complicated structure as that of a $A_\infty$-category for such a seemingly easy problem?